# Trace Network Packets through a network

Tags: networking

I want to trace packets as they move from my host to the destination - something like 'traceroute'. However, I need to know what to what port the packets are accepted at each of the network nodes while 'traceroute' gives me only the node.

Is this possible ? What tools should I use ?

Answer (score 1):

By network nodes, I assume you mean router in the path. The question makes no sense since ports are transport layer addresses, but routing happens with network layer addresses.

When network traffic is routed, a router will strip off the layer-2 frame and inspect the layer-3 destination address (IP, IPX, etc.) in the layer-3 packet. The router never sees the layer-4 segment, so it knows nothing about the layer-4 address (TCP, UPD, SPX, etc. port). The router will switch the layer-3 packet to the next interface and encapsulate it in a new layer-2 frame for that interface, before sending it on its way.

Comment: Thanks for making that clear. I was missing some bits